# Xcode: Linking brand new framework to brand new app fails with "image not found"

Tags: xcode, frameworks, dyld

I'm totally new to Xcode and Objective-C, but an experienced (web) programmer otherwise. I want to create an app that includes a self-made framework.

Now I've read quite a bit on it, I think I've got a reasonable grasp of how OS X resolves dependencies at runtime, and the role of @rpath, @executable_path and @loader_path.

I did the following to create the framework:

1. Create new Cocoa Framework named Test.
2. Set installation directory to "@rpath".
3. Add "Test.h" to public headers.
4. Click run.
5. Right click on Test.framework under "Products", choose Show in Finder. It's a directory called "Test.framework" in the "Debug" directory of the project. It seems to have reasonable contents (Versions/A directory and symlinks to "Headers", "Resources" and the "Test" binary)

I did the following to create the app:

1. Create new Cocoa app named "TestApp".
2. Add test framework to project. 
   Choose "Add files to project".
   Select "Test.framework" directory from "Release" directory of the Test framework project.
   "Copy items into destination group's folder" is checked
   Leave "Create groups for any added folders." on.
3. Make sure framework files are copied to application bundle.
   Choose "Add Build Phase" -> "Add Copy Files"
   Drag Test.framework folder (or group?) from the sidebar into the Copy Files area.
4. Add an extra "framework search path" named "@executable_path/../Frameworks"

When I choose run, I get the following warning during build:

> Build target TestApp
>
> Ld /Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Products/Debug/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/meryn/Work/test-app/TestApp
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/meryn/Work/test-app/TestApp "-F@executable_path/../Frameworks" -filelist /Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Intermediates/TestApp.build/Debug/TestApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Cocoa -framework Test -o /Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Products/Debug/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F@executable_path/../Frameworks'

I can imagine this warning is to be expected, as Ld may not know about "@executable_path" at all. Is this correct?

Subsequently, running the app fails with:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Test.framework/Versions/A/Test
>     Referenced from: /Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Products/Debug/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp
>     Reason: image not found

The peculiar thing is that the TestApp.app package does contain a Frameworks directory, with the Test.framework directory inside. Given what I understand about how OS X would search for dependencies, I think the search path that I added should resolve fine.

This is on XCode 4.6, OS X 10.8.

`otool -L TestApp` gives

> TestApp:
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
>
> @rpath/Test.framework/Versions/A/Test (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.11.0)
>
> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
>
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1187.33.0)

Is it ok to see "@rpath" unexpanded here?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you DID add the framework to the copy-phase, so it exists inside the bundle, at runtime, which is inside your target app, which is in the derived data folder? I suspect something is wrong with the framework file you've added.  Try deleting it and adding it again to the project.

Comment: Well, inside /Users/meryn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-ajwvknoonliuqqfaqxacxrmapyfz/Build/Products/Debug/TestApp.app (the thing that gets built) I have Contents/Frameworks/Test.framework , which includes a symlink to a "Test" binary file, amongst other things. I'm not sure what you mean by the "bundle". Is the bundle equivalent to the app "folder"? In Finder it says "Show Package Contents" so I figured it was called a package. I'll try re-adding anyway. Who knows. :)

Comment: No joy. Are there any other things I could look into? I don't mind learning a bit about OS X (that is, its development infrastructure) in the meantime. For example, is there a way to check if "image not found" simply means "cannot find the file" or that the file is corrupted or so? Can I run dyld manually, applying it to the app "package" (or the app binary inside it) that got build?

Comment: Is "dyld" a stand-alone program?  I think  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html suggests it's so. Yet, I don't seem to have dyld in my PATH. Where would I find it on my system?

Comment: Most interesting thing perhaps is knowing what dyld is expanding "@rpath" to in this case. It would help if its output was a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the library identifier is set to an `@rpath`-prefixed path, the application linking to the library needs to specify one or more `-rpath` options indicating what `dyld` should substitute the `@rpath` variable with when searching for the library at runtime. A typical value would be `@loader_path/../Frameworks` if you're copying your framework in to `TestApp.app/Contents/Frameworks`. You can set the value of the `-rpath` arguments using the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` ('Runpath Search Paths') configuration setting in Xcode on your TestApp target.

> I can imagine this warning is to be expected, as Ld may not know about "@executable_path" at all. Is this correct?

It's not useful to add `@executable_path/../Frameworks` to Xcode's framework search paths. The framework search paths are a build-time concept of the static linker (`ld`), while the `@executable_path` variables are a runtime concept of the dynamic linker (`dyld`).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This was it! I did not know I needed to use "Runpath Search Paths" (under "Linking") instead of "Framework Search Paths" (under "Search Paths"). Sorry for responding so late. I got somehow logged out so I missed the notification, and got no email notification as well.

Comment: I am trying to execute an old app in the current xcode and started getting annoying rpath errors. I tried everything but couldn't fix it. This is what I am getting: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle. I do appreciate a light shed.